# Where are cookies stored for an android app?

Tags: android

I'm just wondering where cookies are stored for an android app?  I have looked through the /data/data/myApp directory but didn't see anything that looked like cookies.  The app I'm writing definitely utilizes cookies through use of the CookieStore.  I'm just wondering where they are natively stored.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure they aren't only stored in-memory within that object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my App I can tell you that the cookies are not stored/cached you need to do that by your own. Just subclass the cookiestore class or serialized by your own.

In my App I do both,  that mean I just store the cookies of the for me relevant domains.